# Bend text and rectangle as a group

Tags: inkscape

Can someone please show me how to bend text and rectangle behind it as one unit?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the text to a path (`Path > Object to Path`) before you can apply a path effect. Then you can group both the 'A' and the rectangle together and apply `Bend`.